# how to split a string with special pattern using regular expression and save it to a list in python

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have a string like this:

```
'{"po": 118.0, "count": 1.0}, {"po": 124.0, "count": 1.0}, {"po": 132.0, "count": 2.0}'
```

I want to split this string and save them into a list like this using python:

```
 ['{"po": 118.0, "count": 1.0}', '{"po": 124.0, "count": 1.0}', '{"po": 132.0, "count": 2.0}']
```

When I do this :

```
r=re.split(r"['{}']", s)
```

But I receive this result, which is not what I want :

```
['', '"po": 118.0, "count": 1.0', ', ', '"po": 124.0, "count": 1.0', ', ', '"po": 132.0, "count": 2.0', '']
```

Would you please guide me on how to use a regular expression to split the string?

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks a lot like a fragment from some JSON content, and, if so, then you might want to work with the original valid JSON.  If you must proceed at your current starting point, then I would suggest using `re.findall` here:

```py
inp = '{"po": 118.0, "count": 1.0}, {"po": 124.0, "count": 1.0}, {"po": 132.0, "count": 2.0}'
output = re.findall(r'\{.*?\}', inp)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
['{"po": 118.0, "count": 1.0}', '{"po": 124.0, "count": 1.0}', '{"po": 132.0, "count": 2.0}']
```

This approach should be fine assuming your input doesn't have any nested content.

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try the following:

```
import re

str = '{"po": 118.0, "count": 1.0}, {"po": 124.0, "count": 1.0}, {"po": 132.0, "count": 2.0}'
r = re.split(r'(?<=}),\s*(?={)', str)
print(r)
```

Output:

```
['{"po": 118.0, "count": 1.0}', '{"po": 124.0, "count": 1.0}', '{"po": 132.0, "count": 2.0}']
```